# Interfacing a slower clock module with a faster dual port block RAM?

Tags: arrays, memory, xilinx

I am trying to interface a module (let's call it main_module) with a dual port block RAM (implemented through the logic core available in Xilinx-ISE). The two modules run at different clocks ( main_module at a much slower clockA than the RAM at clockB). In my design, I have two cases :

1. Fill a byte sized array first at clockA and when it is filled, write it to the BRAM at clockB frequency, while a new set of values start filling the array from the next cycle of clockA (meaning array filling continues undisturbed while the memory is being written to!)  or
2. Read a byte from the BRAM at clockB frequency and then write it to the byte sized array in main_module at clockA.

This undeniably needs synchronization between the two modules. I have tried to implement a "request-acknowledgement handshaking" method for synchronization. It works perfectly fine for case 2 but gives erroneous results for case 1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Everything works at clockA, but the BRAM at clockB. I suppose it's designed for practice. Anyway, we would need to see the progress (e.g. your code) to be able to help you.

Comment: Okay after going through the literature available on synchronization and its schemes, I have come to the conclusion that an Asynchronous FIFO would be the best option since the data stream is continuous. My question now is that can the "din" and "dout" ports of the AFIFO be accessed in a bit-wise rather than a byte-wise fashion?